# HEAP SORT TOP DOWN

Tags: heapsort

> Unhandled exception at 0x00EF140E in Homework2_FA.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x006F68DC.

I dont understand why this error appears.

```
void build_heap_TD(int array[], int array_size) 
{       
    for (int i = 2; i <= array_size; i++)       
    max_heap_insertion(array, array[i],array_size);//here appears the error 
}
```

this is my `max_heap_insertion` function I want a TOP DOWN approach

```
void max_heap_insertion(int array[], int key, int array_size)
{
    int heap_size = array_size;
    array[heap_size] = array[heap_size + 1];
    array[heap_size] = 999999;
    heap_increase_key(array, array[heap_size], key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on here, but most likely array indexes in your (unknown) language are zero-based, so your `i <= array_size` condition should really be `i < array_size`.